# "Ну когда" в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация

> А ещё нас волновали судьбы искусства. Мы ведь только о том и говорили.
>   Ну когда не хулиганили и не играли в преферанс.

Запятой не требуется? после "ну"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**НУ. II. *частица.***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D1%83&all=x) *Сниж.*
**4.** Употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности, **подчёркивает значение** того или другого слова. *Ну конечно, это неправда. Ну какой холод! Ну что за жизнь: ни денег, ни чести, ни удовольствия. Ну как не порадеть родному человечку* (Грибоедов).

Мне кажется, что запятая не нужна.

*— А твои планы какие? — решила сменить тему Анька. — Ну когда все закончится?* (С. Садов. Ледяная принцесса)

Comment: ***Ну когда все закончится?*** - мой случай, спасибо.